# How to position UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

How do you position your UINavigationController on the top edge of your ipad..? Please see screenshot below..

[image]

I have a login screen, when i clicked the button.. I Will issue this command to display my main screen..

```
 HomeScreenViewController *controller = [[HomeScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeScreenViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.view addSubview:controller.view];
```

Comment: Check the size of your nib. It looks like it's smaller than the screen can hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setFrame` (message) to change the position of this view controller.

```
CGRect frame = [controller.view frame];

// or as much as you like or (-) depending where you want to move it.
frame.origin.y += 100;
[controller.view setFrame:frame];
```